# How to properly decode utf7 file names obtained from an IMAP server

Tags: locale, character-encoding, conversion, imap, i18n

I have a few directories that I downloaded from an IMAP server.

Example:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1
.
./&BCEEPwQwBDw-
./&BCMENAQwBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-
./inbox
./&BCcENQRABD0EPgQyBDgEOgQ4-
./&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-
./&BBgEQQRFBD4ENARPBEkEOAQ1-
./Archive
```

These are Cyrillic names encoded in UTF-7.
As far as I understand, utf-7 encoding units are all valid Unicode codepoints <127, at the same time valid ASCII. This means that I can copy, paste, pipe and cat them wherever I want.

Let's do a conversion:

```
$ ls | iconv -f utf7 -t utf8
&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-/
&BBgEQQRFBD4ENARPBEkEOAQ1-/
&BCEEPwQwBDw-/
&BCMENAQwBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-/
&BCcENQRABD0EPgQyBDgEOgQ4-/
Archive/
inbox/
```

Wat? No effect? `iconv -l` lists both utf-7 and utf-8.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A quick test converting Cyrillic from UTF8 to UTF7

```
echo 'Here we go. Це коротке речення' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-7
Here we go. +BCYENQ +BDoEPgRABD4EQgQ6BDU +BEAENQRHBDUEPQQ9BE8
```

Reading a [description for UTF7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) encoding I can see that (roughly speaking) each encoded string must be preceded by `+`. There is no such prefix in your UTF7 directory listing.

Now, as you've seen, converting the `&` to `+` in the data you have extracted doesn't generate valid codepoints,

```
echo '&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-/' | tr '&' + | iconv -f utf-7 -t utf-8
От
iconv: (stdin):1:2: cannot convert
```

BUT, if you take the file names themselves you do get a valid conversion once you switch the `&` to `+`,

```
echo '&BCMENAQwBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-' | tr '&' + | iconv -f utf-7 -t utf-8
Удаленные
```

Comment: won't work with the fifth file (`Оторавленные`) because of the comma `echo '&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-' | tr '&' + | iconv -f utf-7 -t utf-8`. The comma should be removed too (with `tr '&,' ...`). But it may be more to that filename mangling.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this question is ill-posed. The thing is that IMAP (ab)uses utf-7. It's almost utf-7, but not quite. Eventually I solved my problem by using this the php code from php documentation's comment:

[PHP Documentation for imap-utf7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf7-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Perl module for decoding (or encoding) between IMAP's modified UTF-7 and UTF-8 or other encodings: [Encode::IMAPUTF7](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::IMAPUTF7). That makes it quite easy to decode directly at the command-line.

It is usually not installed by default. To insall it on Debian-based systems (Ubuntu etc.):

```
sudo apt install libencode-imaputf7-perl
```

Or on MacOS:

```
cpanp i Encode::IMAPUTF7
```

An example one-liner to rename all files or folders under the current directory in a Bash terminal to UTF-8:

```bsh
find . -depth -name '*&*' | while read x; do new=$(perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::decode(\"IMAP-UTF-7\", shift)' "$x") && mv -v "$x" "$new"; done
```

or split on more lines for readability:

```bsh
find . -depth -name '*&*' \
| while read x; do
    new=$(perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::decode(\"IMAP-UTF-7\", shift)' "$x") \
      && mv -v "$x" "$new";
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

**bash + PHP**

Tested code

```
php -r 'echo mb_convert_encoding("&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-", "UTF-8", "UTF7-IMAP");'
```

The expected result

```
Отправленные
```

Explanation

From "php --help"

```
-r <code> Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
```

mb_convert_encoding PHP function manual

https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

List of the supported encodings

https://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: Note that it needs the `mbstring` extension (`php-mbstring` package on Debian-based systems).

Answer (score 0):

On recent GNU systems at least `iconv` does support a `UTF-7-IMAP` encoding. You can't feed the output of `ls` to it though as newline is not a valid character in there:

```
$ ls | iconv -f UTF-7-IMAP
Archiveiconv: illegal input sequence at position 7
```

With `-c`, it ignores the characters it can't decode:

```
$ ls | iconv -cf UTF-7-IMAP
ArchiveОтправленныеИсходящиеЧерновикиСпамУдаленныеinbox
```

Or you could feed each file name individually to `iconv`:

```
$ for f in *; do printf %s "$f" | iconv -f UTF-7-IMAP; echo; done
Archive
Отправленные
Исходящие
Черновики
Спам
Удаленные
inbox
```

Or do:

```
$ printf '%s&AAo-' * | iconv -f UTF-7-IMAP
Archive
Отправленные
Исходящие
Черновики
Спам
Удаленные
inbox
```

Where `&AAo-` is the UTF-7-IMAP encoding of newline.

Most programming languages have bindings for the standard `iconv(3)` interface. For instance, in `perl`:

```
$ perl -MText::Iconv -le '$c = Text::Iconv->new(qw(UTF-7-IMAP UTF-8));
                          print $c->convert($_) for @ARGV' -- *
Archive
Отправленные
Исходящие
Черновики
Спам
Удаленные
inbox
```

So you could rename those files using `perl`'s `rename` (here with the one from File::Rename 2.0.1, beware there are several variants and versions thereof of `rename`) with:

```
$ rename -n -- '
    use Text::Iconv;
    our $c //= Text::Iconv->new(qw(UTF-7-IMAP UTF-8));
    $_ = $c->convert($_)' *
rename(&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-, Отправленные)
rename(&BBgEQQRFBD4ENARPBEkEOAQ1-, Исходящие)
rename(&BCcENQRABD0EPgQyBDgEOgQ4-, Черновики)
rename(&BCEEPwQwBDw-, Спам)
rename(&BCMENAQwBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-, Удаленные)
```