# I need to create a pipe to convert string from UTF-8 to UTF-7-IMAP

Tags: unicode, conversion, imap

To automate the command line creation of hundreds of directories in IMAP maildirs, I would need to be able to convert UTF-8 strings to UTF-7-IMAP on the fly.

In php, I found a way to do it with a string passed as an argument, but it's not very practical, and it requires installing php.

```
<?php
echo mb_convert_encoding($argv[1], "UTF7-IMAP", "UTF8");
?>
```

Iconv doesn't seem to know about UTF-7-IMAP.

I found a syntax that allows you to do the opposite:

```
echo "Sant&AOk-" | tr "&" "+" | iconv -f UTF-7 -t UTF-8
Santé
```

But it is not reversible that simply (the final '-' is missing)

```
echo "Santé" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-7 | tr '+' '&'
Sant&AOk
```

I can find very little about this on the internet.

Edit:

I found this working fine:

```
perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode("IMAP-UTF-7", shift)' "Santé"
```

but how to create a pipe?

```
echo "Santé" | perl ...
```

Comment: Related - [How to properly decode utf7 file names obtained from an IMAP server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/614046/100397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iconv` (or at least the 2.36 version available on Debian 12) knows about the encoding you need:

```shell
$ iconv -l | grep -i imap
UTF-7-IMAP//
```

So:

```shell
$ printf '%s\n' 'Santé' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-7-IMAP; echo ''
Sant&AOkACg-
$ printf '%s' 'Santé' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-7-IMAP; echo ''
Sant&AOk-
```

Note that both outputs lack a line feed (so an echo add it at the end of the result for readability), but the line feed character *was* encoded, thus two different results with or without LF added at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

While [using `iconv`](/a/757627) (or `recode`, `uconv` and other tools dedicated to charset conversion), assuming they support IMAP-UTF-7 would be the best approach here, for your `perl` command to work on input rather than arguments, you could do:

```
$ echo Santé | perl -CIi  -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -pe '$_ = Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode("IMAP-UTF-7", $_)'
Sant&AOkACg-
```

`-p` is for the `sed` mode, where `perl` reads its input (or the files¹ given as arguments) and runs the code on each line like `sed` does. `$_` is the equivalent of `sed`'s pattern space except that in `perl` contrary to `sed`, it does contain the line delimiter.

With `-CIi`, we tell `perl` stdin and other input (like that coming from files in arguments) is expected to be text encoded in UTF-8, so it will decode it automatically upon input.

---

<sup>¹ or output of commands and more as in `perl -pe '$_ = uc $_' 'uname|'` outputting `LINUX` on a Linux-based machine for instance. It uses the `<>` diamond operator described in `perldoc perlop` behind the scene.</sup>

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, @A.B made me realize that I could use iconv which is more simple for me, but your answer explains me how to use perl as I asked.